# Prove that $\mathbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{-3}\right]$ is not a Dedekind domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Prove that $\mathbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{-3}\right]$
  is not a Dedekind domain.

Comment: why would some one consider "Proving" your statement if you do not show what have you tried??

Comment: It would be useful if you could tell us what you have tried. This helps us to understand what you already know so we can better focus our help. Also, people around here get touchy when people just post a question without motivation etc. as they are unwilling to simply do others homework for them, moreover they dislike it when a third party steps in and does the homework for them anyway so questions like this which merely states a question tend to get closed (pending adding more info). Adding in what you have tried and where you came across it will stop your question getting closed in this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $(1+\sqrt{-3})(1-\sqrt{-3})=2\cdot2$

Comment: In $\mathbb{Z}\left[\sqrt{-3}\right]$, $2$ is irreducible but not prime. Maybe it's usefull.